# Split text and insert words in sql database

Tags: c#

I want to select file contains `.txt` and split all strings in each text into array 
then insert the divided words into sql database (word, counter) and count the repeated words in each text by counter that lead to unrepeated words in database tables>>

(1)-counter code is incorrect I found several errors in my code >> (i want to prevent a repeat of word at the same time calculate how many times repeated word in databases ,by using counter.)
(2)- my code has static path (just one text ),but I want user to select his file which he want to split. (browse.. button) 
(3-)sql database could not show Arabic Words (?????)

```
namespace lib123
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn;
        SqlCommand sqlComm;
        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdptr;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
           sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
           sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
           sqlAdptr = new SqlDataAdapter();
           sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn;
           sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=007-PC\\SQLEXPRESS ;Initial Catalog= Email_DB;Integrated Security =True ";

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillGrid();             
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {              
            if (sqlConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                sqlConn.Open();

            // sqlComm = sqlConn.CreateCommand(); 

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\007\Desktop\spam-email\spamenglish.txt"); //get the file
            string stringWithMultipleSpaces = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); //load file to string
            streamReader.Close();

            Regex r = new Regex(" +"); //specify delimiter (spaces)
            string[] words = r.Split(stringWithMultipleSpaces); //(convert string to array of words)

            int c = 1;
            string strQry = "select ISNULL( max(id),0) as id from word_tb ";
            sqlComm.CommandText = strQry;

            int LastID = int.Parse(sqlComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            string x ;
            String st = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                string y = words[i];
                for (int j = 0; j <LastID; j++)
                {
                 x = "select word from word_tb where id = j";
                sqlComm.CommandText = x ;   
                    if (x.Equals(y))
                    {
                        c = c + 1;
                        string sql = "INSERT INTO word_tb (count) VALUES ('" + c + "') where id = i";
                        sqlComm.CommandText = sql;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LastID = LastID + 1;
                        st += "INSERT INTO word_tb(id, word,count) VALUES('" + LastID + "', '" + words[i].ToString() + "','" + c + "');";

                        //st += "INSERT INTO word_tb(word) VALUES('" + words[i].ToString() + "');";

                    }
                }
            }
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlComm.CommandText = st;
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            FillGrid();
        }
        private void FillGrid()
        {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            string   strQry = "select * from word_tb ";             
            sqlComm.CommandText = strQry;
            sqlAdptr.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
            sqlAdptr.Fill (tbl) ;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        }
        //private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    string str = "DELETE FROM word_tb";
        //    sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //    sqlComm.CommandText = str;
        //    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();


        //            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay... so what is your question?

Comment: 1-counter code is incorrect I found several errors in my code >>>>(2)- my code has static path (just one text ),but I want user to select his file which he want to split. (browse.. button) <<<< (3)-sql database could not show Arabic Words

Answer (score 0):

> 1-counter code is incorrect I found several errors in my code?

you can use below code to split the File `Text` into `words` based on `space` as `delimiter`.

**Code:**

```
 String strAllData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\007\Desktop\spam-email\spamenglish.txt");
 String[]  words = strAllData.Split(' ');
```

> 2- my code has static path (just one text ),but I want user to select
>   his file which he want to split. (browse.. button) ?

you can use `OpenFileDialog` control to let user choose the file which he/she wants to work on.

**Code:**

```
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            String strAllData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileDialog.FileName);
            String[]  words = strAllData.Split(' ');
        }
```

> 3 -sql database could not show Arabic Words (?????) ?

`Sql Server` can not show `Uni Code` characters when you fire a SELECT Query because you have created your table columns/feilds as `varchar`.

**Solution:**  if you want to get the `Arabic` characters when you fire a `SELECT` query you should create your table columns to accept `Uni Code` characters using `NVARCHAR` datatype instead of `VARCHAR`. `N` stands for `National language character set`.

**Step1 :** create your table columns as `NVARCHAR` as below:

```
create table sample(
[name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL)
```

**Step 2:**  Use `N` as prefix while inserting Data into `NVARCHAR` columns. N as prefix tells that all following characters are `Uni Code` characters.

**Code:**

```
INSERT INTO sample VALUES(N'لا أتكلم العربية');
```

Now if you fire a `SELECT` Query you will be able to see the `Arabic` Characters.

Comment: the first problem (1) , that i want to prevent a repeat of word at the same time calculate how many times repeated word in databases ,by using counter.??